# Dplyr SELECT issue with single apostrophe

Tags: r, select, dplyr, escaping

I am trying to use the select function with the dplyr package for the following variable:

`APP-Reviewer’s Observations on Research Protocols`

My assumption is that I need to escape the the single apostrophe in the variable name as I get the following error when I try and select the variable:

> Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) :
> object 'APP-Reviewerâ\200\231s Observations on Research Protocols' not found

When I try using an escape character, I  get the following error:

> Error: '\’' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "`APP-Reviewer\’"

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to escape the single apostrophe in if you're using backticks.  Note also that the single quote in this instance is a smart quote `’` not a straight quote `'`.  Using  `... %>% select(\`APP-Reviewer’s Observations on Research Protocols\`)` should be sufficient. If you continue to have problems you'll need to post a sample of your data (use `dput(head(df))`) and the code used that generated the error.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a variable name, e.g. for a column of a data.frame, then try enclosing the variable using ` marks. This is the backquote/backtick mark, found on the same key as the tilde (~) to the left of the number 1. They can be used to denote variable names when the variable contains non-standard characters.

E.g.

```r
data(mtcars)
mtcars %>%
  mutate(`horse power` = hp,                                 # space in variable name
         `4th gear` = gear == 4,                             # variable starts with number
         `David's` = rownames(mtcars) == "Mazda RX4") %>%    # variable contains quote
  select(hp, `horse power`, gear, `4th gear`, `David's`) %>%
  head(4)

#                 hp horse power gear 4th gear David's
# Mazda RX4      110         110    4     TRUE    TRUE
# Mazda RX4 Wag  110         110    4     TRUE   FALSE
# Datsun 710      93          93    4     TRUE   FALSE
# Hornet 4 Drive 110         110    3    FALSE   FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks Simon. This is a variable name and I am already using the backquote\backtick mark to enclose it, which is why I found it weird that it is causing me errors. I am wondering if it is an encoding issue.